# Voice navigation not working after MSDKUI 2.1.1 Update when adding GuidanceManeuverMonitor

Tags: swift, here-api

I have updated my MSDKUI project from 2.0.0 to 2.1.1 and have made some changes make the navigation work.
My project is based on "GuideMeToHERE". The updated podfile is:
target 'GuideMeToHERE' do
    platform :ios, '12.0'
    pod 'HEREMapsUI', '2.1.1'
end

Voice Guidance stops working when I set up the GuidanceManeuverMonitor.

This is my function setUpGuidanceViews(route: NMARoute)

```
    private func setUpGuidanceViews(route: NMARoute) {

        NMANavigationManager.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        //*** If I comment these three lines out the voice guidance works!
        maneuverMonitor = GuidanceManeuverMonitor(route: route)
        maneuverMonitor.delegate = self
        customizeGuidanceManeuverView()
```

What can I do to have the maneuver monitor working and have voice guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by changing one of the delegates to be more specific:

```
    //NMANavigationManager.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    NavigationManagerDelegateDispatcher.shared.add(delegate: self)
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to @CSchwarz answer I had to implement the following NMANavigationManagerDelegate function:

```
func navigationManager(_ navigationManager: NMANavigationManager, shouldPlayVoiceFeedback text: String?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

and

```
NavigationManagerDelegateDispatcher.shared.add(delegate: self)
```